# Decompiled and imported into Eclipse and got instantiation error

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android App programming.  I decompiled an APK and imported into Eclipse.  I ran it on an Android emulator and I got the message below on Logcat.  Can someone give me an idea where to start looking.  The app works on the Android phone.  Thanks.

```
11-24 13:41:39.046: D/AndroidRuntime(363): Shutting down VM
11-24 13:41:39.046: W/dalvikvm(363): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.breakeven/com.breakeven.BreakEvenCalculatorActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.breakeven.BreakEvenCalculatorActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.breakeven-1.apk]
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.breakeven.BreakEvenCalculatorActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.breakeven-1.apk]
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
11-24 13:41:39.126: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  ... 11 more
11-24 13:43:41.106: I/Process(363): Sending signal. PID: 363 SIG: 9
11-24 13:44:17.136: D/AndroidRuntime(393): Shutting down VM
11-24 13:44:17.136: W/dalvikvm(393): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.breakeven/com.breakeven.BreakEvenCalculatorActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.breakeven.BreakEvenCalculatorActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.breakeven-1.apk]
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.breakeven.BreakEvenCalculatorActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.breakeven-1.apk]
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
11-24 13:44:17.206: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  ... 11 more
11-24 13:44:23.546: I/Process(393): Sending signal. PID: 393 SIG: 9
11-24 13:49:28.816: D/AndroidRuntime(403): Shutting down VM
11-24 13:49:28.816: W/dalvikvm(403): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
```

Comment: what you are trying to develop

Comment: The fourth line clearly states `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.breakeven.BreakEvenCalculatorActivity`. Are you sure this class exists or corresponding library is loaded?